# How to integrate simple saml in laravel

Tags: simplesamlphp

I am trying to integrate using this https://simplesamlphp.org/download but not able to understand the steps. i am completely new for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a laravel saml package that uses simpleSAMLphp:
https://github.com/mlntn/laravel-saml

That will add SAML support to your laravel app turning it a SAML Service Provider.

Comment: Thanks for the response, My application is build on laravel 5.2. Does the above git link will support for 5.2.

Comment: I guess:  Check description of composer:
https://github.com/mlntn/laravel-saml/blob/master/composer.json#L3
It says lavarel 5.*